# Remove multiples urls of same type from google webmaster

Tags: google-search-console

I accidentally kept some urls of type `www.example.com/abc/?id=1` in which value of id can vary from 1 to 200. I don't want these to appear in search so i am using remove url feature of google webmasters tools. How can i remove all these types of urls in one shot? i tried `www.example.com/abc/?id=*` but this doesn't worked!

Answer (score 0):

just block them using robots.txt ie.

```
User-agent: * 
Disallow: /junk.html 
Disallow: /foo.html 
Disallow: /bar.html
```